# Javascript getTime() returns negative value in apple's script editor for mac automation

Tags: javascript, macos, javascriptcore

I was using applescript for Mac automation but decided to switch to javascript. I am using Apple's built-in Script Editor javascript feature which is using the JavaScriptCore framework from what I understand.

Starting this I came along a issue that seems to be really basic and drives me crazy. I am not able to deal with dates as I am used from javascript.
The following code should give me the milliseconds passed since January 1, 1970, but instead it returns a negative value:

```
app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

today = new Date();

app.displayDialog(today.getTime()); // returns -1412870369
```

I hope you can help me understanding what is wrong and how to use the date functionalities as known from javascript in general.
Thanks!

Edit: I think the reason might be that the float number is converted to an integer and as it exceeds the range of integers. However, I don't know why this happens or how to prevent it.

Comment: I agree it is most likely due to a binary overflow.  Where is it returning a float?

Comment: Are you using a [`JSContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore/jscontext) instance to access the value computed in JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean with where it is returning a float? According to javascript documentation the function getTime() of the date class returns a float number, but when I use it in script editor as shown above it just don't work. 
I don't use a `JSContext` instance. I thought this is needed if I code in objective-c or swift and want to evaluate javascript code? Please correct me if I am wrong but I thought that apple's script editor's javascript feature would allow me to code javascript extended by some features for event handling?